# Building error System.Windows.Interactivity access denied

Tags: c#, wpf

Originally all works smoothly, but when I add some event method to my class, and build the wpf, I get error like

> System.Windows.Interactivity dll access denied in Debug Folder in the project Folder

and I try to do as

[HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/c7d2beb6-f334-4687-bc7c-f2f651eb8064/systemwindowsinteractivity-dll)   ,

I go to the Blend Folder and find the System.Windows.Interactivity dll,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries
```

and copy to my Debug Folder, but a messageBox show says "the file has existed, and you have to be the administrator to replace this file here",

but it's strange that the control panel shows I'm real Administrator to my computer, but I still can't replace it.

Neither can I delete the file, when I wnat to delete the dll, I got the same message to ask me to be the administrator,

so why I can't access this file, really strange, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to restart my computer, after restart , I just build directly and success .

And I found another way is to check ,in task manager if your debug exe is running in background, if so, close it, then run the project again.